# How to make vim code folding colors more readable

Tags: gnome-terminal, vim, colors, color-management, vi

I use code folding in vim, e.g. za, zc, zR, ZM

But when the code is folded the resulting color - light blue on white is very hard to read for me with poor contrast

[image]

#### I have tried changing my profile's light blue color

[image]

#### to red

[image]

and starting new windows but I still get the light blue on white

How can I make the light blue on white on code folds be red on white ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It may be easier to add something like the code below to your `.vimrc` file, rather than changing profile settings in the GUI.

```
syntax enable "(syntax on also works)  Note that quotes are a comment in .vimrc
highlight Folded ctermbg=White ctermfg=Red
```

If you already have a `highlight` line for other purposes add this as a new line below it, e.g. have two highlight lines as opposed to appending it (invalid format).

See [here](http://alvinalexander.com/linux/vi-vim-editor-color-scheme-syntax) for more details and different options.